# Polyspace: asserted scalar range of min..max at floating types

Tags: c, static-analysis

I'm using a DRS xml file in Mathworks Polyspace to fine-tune some assertions. When I want full range assertion, then I place the line below:

```
<scalar assert_range="min..max" name="myVariable" />
```

What is the exact meaning of `min` and `max` when the variable is of type `float`?
Will it be asserted for `-INFINITY..INFINITY` too or only `-FLT_MAX..FLT_MAX` ?

Comment: Apart from `NaN` what benefit would there be for the range `-INFINITY..INFINITY`? BTW note that `FLT_MIN` in C is the smallest non-negative value.

Comment: Other possibilities is `-HUGE_VALF..HUGE_VALF`, or depending on type,  `DBL_MAX, HUGE_VAL, LDBL_MAX, HUGE_VALL`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the comments, I edited the question. I'm looking for errors in implementation and I believe software should handle INFINITY values nicely.

Comment: @chux That's also possibile, I would even assert for NaN. Mathworks help for DRS files is not so verbose.

Comment: @WeatherVane Actually, `FLT_MIN` is the smallest positive normalized value.

Answer (score 0):

The min..max is range for the intrinsic type of the variable being constrained (int, float, long, etc)

If you're using an enumeration, you can use min..max for the range of the underlying type for the enum, or, you can use enum_min..enum_max for the range of the enum itself.

More details in the doc for [Data Range Specification](https://www.mathworks.com/help/codeprover/ug/specify-constraints.html).